# how to split 2 hashes into 3 hashes?

Tags: perl, hash

How can I split 2 hashes, that contain some common keys, into 3 hashes, when:

```
%input_hash_1 = ( key1 => 1, key2 => 2, key3 => 3, , key4 => 4 );
%input_hash_2 = ( key3 => 3, key4 => 4, key5 => 5, , key6 => 6 );
```

and the output required is:

```
%output_hash_1 = ( key1 => 1, key2 => 2 );  # keys in input_hash_1 && not in input_hash_2
%output_hash_2 = ( key3 => 3, key4 => 4 );  # keys in input_hash_1 &&     in input_hash_2
%output_hash_3 = ( key5 => 5, key6 => 6 );  # keys in input_hash_2 && not in input_hash_1
```

in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my %o_hash_1 = map { !exists $i_hash_2{$_} ? ($_=>$i_hash_1{$_}) : () } keys %i_hash_1;
my %o_hash_2 = map {  exists $i_hash_2{$_} ? ($_=>$i_hash_1{$_}) : () } keys %i_hash_1;
my %o_hash_3 = map { !exists $i_hash_1{$_} ? ($_=>$i_hash_2{$_}) : () } keys %i_hash_2;
```

or

```
my %o_hash_1 = map { $_=>$i_hash_1{$_} } grep !exists $i_hash_2{$_}, keys %i_hash_1;
my %o_hash_2 = map { $_=>$i_hash_1{$_} } grep  exists $i_hash_2{$_}, keys %i_hash_1;
my %o_hash_3 = map { $_=>$i_hash_2{$_} } grep !exists $i_hash_1{$_}, keys %i_hash_2;
```

or using `pairmap` from `List::Util` (since v1.29)

```
use List::Util 'pairmap';
my %o_hash_1 = pairmap { !exists $i_hash_2{$a} ? ($a=>$b) : () } %i_hash_1;
```

or using perl `5.20+` and [`key/value`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/pod/perldata.pod#Key/Value_Hash_Slices) hash slice

```
my %o_hash_1 = %i_hash_1{ grep !exists $i_hash_2{$_}, keys %i_hash_1};
```

Comment: which one is faster ?

Comment: @user3787639 first should be faster due less operations.

Comment: `delete @$_{keys %i_hash_2} for \my %o_hash_1 = %i_hash_1;` (DRY temptation)

Comment: In 5.20+, you can use a kv hash slice instead of map.  `... = %i_hash_1{ grep ... };`

Answer (score 3):

Set operations are easy with hashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1 = ( key1 => 1, key2 => 2, key3 => 3, key4 => 4 );
my %hash2 = ( key3 => 3, key4 => 4, key5 => 5, key6 => 6 );

my %both = %hash1;
exists $hash2{$_} or delete $both{$_} for keys %hash1;
print Dumper \%both;

my %only1 = %hash1;
delete @only1{ keys %hash2 };
print Dumper \%only1;

my %only2 = %hash2;
delete @only2{ keys %hash1 };
print Dumper \%only2;
```

See also [Set::Light](http://p3rl.org/Set%3a%3aLight).